# AEM 6.5 Maven Build Compilation Error with Uber jar 6.5.3 ResponsiveGridExporter API does not return AllowedComponentsExporter

Tags: java, maven, aem

Getting below compilation error with maven build using aem-uber jar 6.5.3

The type com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.model.impl.export.AllowedComponentsExporter cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

The ResponsiveGridExporter API does not return com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.model.impl.export.AllowedComponentsExporter interface. The com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.model.impl package is declared as private package.

https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/aem-6-5/qaq-p/330391

Comment: Are you using the Uber-Jar with deprecations or without them?

Comment: Did you found the solution? I'm facing similar problem

Comment: @ronnyfm the problem is not with uber jar. This method is private method of Core Responsive Grid component. It is deprecated, but still private and required by the contract of the interface. This problem occurs when trying to override core behaviour of AEM ResponsiveGrid

Comment: Any update / solution with this? I would like to override this method as well (on publish instance I don't want to have this things json model)

Comment: @mkovacek please see if the fix in the answer resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

As a fix, we can create a class with same package `com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.model.impl.export.AllowedComponentsExporter` in our bundle, this resolved the issue for us.